# Filling cell data with mean for each unique name

Tags: r

I have been using R for the past couple days and I have question that I am a little stumped on. I have a dataframe with bidder names and bids where some of the bids are empty. I am having trouble implementing a dynamic way to take the average bid for each unique bidder and apply that to the empty cells. This line of code below will take the mean bid for all of the unique bidders. All I need to do is place the mean value of unique_bid in the empty cells that shares the same bidder.

```
unique_bid <- aggregate(bid ~ bidder, auction[complete.cases(auction),], mean)
```

[Here](https://prnt.sc/nf2bcd) is a picture of what the dataframe looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ave`.

Example:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b=c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA),c= c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

> df
  a  b c
1 1  1 1
2 1  2 2
3 1 NA 3
4 2  4 4
5 2  5 5
6 2 NA 6
```

Do:

```
sel = is.na(df$b)
df$b[sel] = ave(df$b, df$a, FUN = function(x){mean(x, na.rm = T)})[sel]
```

`ave` will use apply the function `FUN` to `df$b` while grouping by `df$a`. The `sel` will select NA elements of `df$b` and replace them by the correponding function's result.

Result:

```
> df
  a   b c
1 1 1.0 1
2 1 2.0 2
3 1 1.5 3
4 2 4.0 4
5 2 5.0 5
6 2 4.5 6
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I'm assuming that the cells that still have NA in them do not have any bids to compare to and should probrably be removed. Thanks again!

Comment: If a particular bid only has NAs then the `mean(x, na.rm=T)` will return `NaN` and the NAs will be replaced as such

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much!